# Statistics with HDFS data

Tags: statistics, hdfs

In our company, we use HDFS. So far everything works out and we can extract data by using queries.

In the past I had worked a lot with Project R. It was always great for my analyses. So I checked Project R and the support of HDFS (rbase, rhdfs,...).

Nevertheless, I am a little bit confused since I found tons of tutorials where they do analyses with simple data saved in CSV files. Don't get me wrong. That's fine but I want to ask if there is a possibility to write queries, extracting the data and do some statistics in one run.

Or in other words: When we talk about statistics for data stored in HDFS, how do you handle this?

Thanks a lot and hopefully some of you can help me out to see pros and cons for my question.

All the best -
Peter

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out  [Apache Hive](https://hive.apache.org/) and [Apache Spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html). Although there are many other option but I am not sure whether you are asking how to work on the data from hdfs when the data is not handed down to you in a file.